# Update your target API level by 31 August 2023 to release updates to your app in kotlin?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I got a mail from the play store that Update your target API level by August 31, 2023 to release updates to your app.

and this is the warning message :

> Update your target API level by 31 August 2023 to release updates to
> your app:
>
> We've detected that your app is targeting an old version of Android.
> To provide users with a safe and secure experience, Google Play
> requires all apps to meet target API level requirements.
>
> From 31 August 2023, if your target API level is not within one year
> of the latest Android release, you won't be able to update your app.
>
> To continue making updates to your app, ensure your app targets
> Android 13 (API level 33).

My app targetSdkVersion is 31 and this warning says that it doesn't necessary to update 33 your targetSdkVersion if your targetSdkVersion is 31.

[image]

it says "when you update your app , you must target api 33 or above"

so I can leave my app targetSdkVersion at 31, but if I want to update it in the future, does the targetSdkVersion have to be 33 right? In this case, I still need to increase my targetSdkVersion from 31 to 33. I just want to ensure that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you want to update your app in the future then the targetSdkVersion must be greater or equal to 33.